# PHP - Calculate profit - 1 order -> Various Products

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making my first steps on programming.
I decided to begin with PHP... so be nice if my question is too simple.

I'm doing a SQL query on a shop database where I get something like this:

```
-- Reference -- Buying Cost -- Selling Cost ---- QUANTITY--Product Name--

-----GGHH-----------5---------------10--------------1------qwqwqwqwqwqw--

-----WEFJ-----------1----------------3--------------2------asasasasasas--

-----ERWW-----------20--------------25--------------1------zxzxzxzxzxzx--

-----GGHH-----------5---------------10--------------1------rtrtrtrtrtrt--

-----GGHH-----------10--------------20--------------2------fgfgfgfgfgfg--

-----GGHH-----------33--------------55--------------1------jkjkjkjkjkjk--
```

1 order has 1 reference and 1 order might have 1 products or more.

Read the above table as each line = a certain product of X quantity that belongs to order Z.

What I want to do is a HTML table with each order Reference and the following profit based on selling cost - buying cost = profit.

I'm not figuring out how I can do it.

If each order only had 1 product it would be easy... but since this structure I'm not figuring it out.

Note: I can't change anything in terms of MySQL database. I only can read from it.

Thank you!!

Comment: step 1 fix the db schema

Comment: You need to start with some basic research on how to SELECT data from the database.  Next, do some research on how to generate the necessary HTML from the results.

Comment: @Dagon let's say I'm not allowed to do any changes on the DB.

Comment: let's say you create your own db schema and learn the right way

Comment: @durbnpoisn I know how to construct a table and I know basic MySQL syntax. Probably I wasn't clear enough. The "table" above represents a query result. Not a table in DB. In fact this is the result of a query involving 3 tables...

Comment: lets say you are, and you should.

Comment: @Drew Probably I wasn't clear enough. The "table" above represents a query result. Not a table in DB. In fact this is the result of a query involving 3 tables...

Comment: fair enough. Show the table schema's, some sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to Andrew Coder.

I made little changes:

```
//DB
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "XXXXXX";
$dbpassword = "YYYYYY";
$dbdatabase = "ZZZZZZ";


$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);     
if($conn->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Error [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "Select distinct 
            ps_orders.reference
        From 
            ps_order_detail Inner Join ps_orders On ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order Inner Join ps_order_state On ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_state.id_order_state 
        Where 
            ps_order_state.delivery = 1";


if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){ 
    die('Error [' . $conn->error . ']');
}

// You'd print your table header here
Print "<table>";
print "<tr><th>Reference</th><th>Profit</th>";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Loop through each unique reference
    $thisref = $row['reference'];
    $profit_query = "   
    Select
          ps_orders.reference,
          ps_order_detail.original_product_price,
          ps_order_detail.original_wholesale_price,
          ps_order_detail.product_quantity
    From
          ps_orders Inner Join
          ps_order_detail On ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order Inner Join
          ps_order_state On ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_state.id_order_state
    Where
        ps_orders.reference ="."'".$thisref."'";

   $profit_raw = $conn->query($profit_query);


   // Reset profit value each parent iteration
   $profit_value = 0;
   while($profit_row = $profit_raw->fetch_assoc()) {
       // Loop through this references items
       $buying_cost    = $profit_row['original_wholesale_price'];
       $selling_cost   = $profit_row['original_product_price'];
       $quantity       = $profit_row['product_quantity'];

       // Do profit math
       $this_profit = ($selling_cost - $buying_cost) * $quantity;

       // Now add to profit value
       $profit_value += $this_profit;

       // Clear re-usable vars for good measure
       unset($buying_cost);
       unset($selling_cost);
       unset($quantity);
   }

   // Now print that items profit
   print "<tr>\n";
   print "\t<td>".$thisref."</td>\n";
   print "\t<td>".$profit_value."</td>\n";
   print "</tr>\n";
}

// Close table
print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this.

```
// Get list of References without duplicates
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `Reference` FROM `table` ORDER BY `Reference` ASC";
$ref_raw = mysql_query($query);

// You'd print your table header here
Print "<table>";
print "<tr><th>Reference</th><th>Profit</th>";

while ($ref_row = mysql_fetch_array($ref_raw)){
    // Loop through each unique reference
    $thisref = $ref_row['Reference'];
    $profit_query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Reference` = '$thisref'";
    $profit_raw = mysql_query($profit_query);

    // Reset profit value each parent iteration
    $profit_value = 0;

    while ($profit_row = mysql_fetch_array($profit_raw)){
        // Loop through this references items
        $buying_cost    = $profit_row['buying_cost'];
        $selling_cost   = $profit_row['selling_cost'];
        $quantity       = $profit_row['quantity'];

        // Do profit math
        $this_profit = ($selling_cost - $buying_cost) * $quantity;

        // Now add to profit value
        $profit_value += $this_profit

        // Clear re-usable vars for good measure
        unset($buying_cost);
        unset($selling_cost);
        unset($quantity);
    }

    // Now print that items profit
    print "<tr>\n";
    print "\t<td>".$thisref."</td>\n";
    print "\t<td>".$profit_value."</td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
}

// Close table
print "</table>";
```

Comment: minus 1 for `mysql_*`

Comment: Yes, I learned harshly after joining stackeoverflow that I need to learn mysqli.  Meant to put a disclaimer in my response to use mysqli, forgot.

Comment: queries are inside loops are almost always wrong, you can use a join and a single query - as we don't know the op's structure i don't know how you think this is going to help

Comment: I'm far from an expert.  My responses can only come from my own understanding/practice.  I simply used the column headers in his example as literal column names, and called the table "table" since a name wasn't provided.  It was meant to be a basic concept type answer, and not necessarily "Here's your perfect code to cut and paste..."

Comment: Not being a snide prick is also an option.

Comment: @AndrewCoder Thank you! Worked Just fine... I'm sharing here my adapted code with mysqli. Kudos!

Comment: As a "final" comment to everyone... this was merely an exercise that I was doing based on my studies. I started coding weeks ago as self-taught... so I wasn't looking for the perfect code. I was looking for the "thinking" that could lead to the solution. Thank you.